# How to retrieve codepage from cURL HTTP response?

Tags: c++, http, unicode, curl

I'm using lib-cURL as a HTTP client to retrieve various pages (can be any URL for that matter).
Usually the data comes as a UTF-8 string and then I just call "MultiByteToWideChar" and it works well.

However, some web-pages still use code-page encoding and I see gibberish if i try to convert those pages to UTF-8.

Is there an easy way to retrieve the code page from the data? or I'll have to scan it manually (for "encoding=") and then translate it accordingly.

If so, how do i get the code-page id from name ([Code Page Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))?

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used DetectInputCodepage in [IMultiLanguage2 interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it worked great !

Answer (score 1):

There are several location where a document can state its encoding:

- the `Content-Type` HTTP header
- the (optional) XML declaration
- the `Content-Type` meta tag inside the document header
- for HTML5 documents the `charset` meta tag.

There are probably even more I've forgotten.

In the end, detecting the actual encoding is rather hard. You really shouldn't do this yourself but use high-level libraries for retrieving and parsing HTML content. I'm sure they are available even for C++, even if they have to be thiefed from the a browser environment. :)

Comment: Thanks for that info I didn't knew it could appear in so many places. However it's not very effective for me, I'm creating a native host that can allow JS Code perform cross-domain HTTP requests and eventually receive his request as plain text. I'll have to parse the entire HTML document and look for those tags just to convert it to a readable text - sounds a bit expensive (run-time wise). However found a nice COM interface that might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741001(v=vs.85).aspx